# Why in my case $(document).click directly calls the function rather than attaching an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler

I work on a game and my goal is this: when the game is over the user can restart the game with a mouse click. 
 But the code `$(document).click(startFunction);` acts like `startFunction();`. 
 I also noticed that if `$(document).click` is added to the stage preceding the "game over" stage, then the first `$(document).click` calls the next function directly and the second `$(document).click` works like it supposed to. 
 What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Here is my JS code. It has been simplified with only the "shell" related to my questions remain intact.

```
dislayedGameDescription();

function gameOver() {
    $(document).off("click");
    // more code...
    $(document).click(moveByComputer);
}

function gameStart() {
    $(document).off("click");
    // more code...
    moveByComputer();
}

function moveByComputer() {
    $(document).off("click");
    // more code... 
    $(".btn").click(moveByUser);
}

function moveByUser() {
    $(".btn").off("click");
    // more code...
    determination();
}

function determination() {
    if (1) {
        if (2) {
            moveByComputer();
        } else {
            $(".btn").click(moveByUser);
        }
    } else {
    
    // I want to place here gameOver(); but it works only if I place
    $(document).click(gameOver);

    // And it acts like gameOver(); here so the next $(document).click in the gameOver function acts normal
    }
}

function dislayedGameDescription() {
    // more code...
    $(document).on("click", gameStart);
}
```

Comment: Why do you add and remove click handlers. Completely unnecessary. Assign the event listeners once and then test a boolean if the click does anything

Comment: Also this is always true `if (1) { if (2) {` because they are truthy values

Comment: mplungjan, thanks for looking at my code. The reason I remove click handlers is as following: in my game there are 4 buttons and the rest of the screen. User controls the game with buttons but starts and restarts the game by clicking anywhere on the screen. My idea is to allows clicks anywhere only when the game is over in order to restart it. If I misunderstood your comment, maybe you can post and example of what you mean. Regarding the if statements, the numbers represent conditions as I have two conditions to evaluate user's input. I removed and replaced them with numbers only to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this code, the behaviour changed:
`return false;` is added at the end of each event handler to cancel click event propagation, from .btn to document for example.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    function gameOver() {
      console.log("gameOver()");
      $(document).off("click");
    // more code...
      $(document).click(moveByComputer);
      return false;
    }

    function gameStart() {
      console.log("gameStart()");
      $(document).off("click");
    // more code...
      moveByComputer();
      return false;
    }

    function moveByComputer() {
      console.log("moveByComputer()");
      $(document).off("click");
      // more code...
      $(".btn").click(moveByUser);
      return false;
    }

    function moveByUser() {
      console.log("moveByUser()");
      $(".btn").off("click");
      // more code...
      determination();
      return false;
    }

    function determination() {
      console.log("determination()");
      if (false && 1) {
        if (2) {
          moveByComputer();
        } else {
          $(".btn").click(moveByUser);
        }
      } else {
        // I want to place here
        gameOver();
        // But it works only if I place
        //$(document).click(gameOver);
        // ...and it acts like gameOver(); here 
        // so the next $(document).click in 
        // the gameOver function acts normal
      }
      return false;
    }


    function dislayedGameDescription() {
      console.log("dislayedGameDescription()");
      // more code...
      $(document).on("click", gameStart);
      return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      dislayedGameDescription();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<button class="btn">Click button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Without return clause, a function returns it's default value = `undefined`.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions .

Comment: Jacouh, thank you for looking at my code. I'll try to incorporate it in my game ASAP and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had weird issues with this before. You could use

```
.bind("click", startFn);
```

instead of

```
.click(startFn);
```

Comment: Luke Weaver, Thanks for looking at my code. FYI .bind is deprecated and you probably should use .on() and .off() instead of .bind() and .unbind() but I do see what you mean. I did try it both ways and the result was the same. So I'm pretty confident that this is not the issue.